# Not seeing folders in view folder in Rails app after scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sublimetext3

I have never had this problem before. I just generated a new scaffold in rails called Cv.  I´m using sumblime 3

It went all very nicely and I can see all related folders in sublime 3 such as `controllers/cvs_controller.rb`, `models/cv.rb`, I can even put `root 'cvs#index'`in my config file and the routing works. But I can't see my views/cvs` folder in sublime, as the screenshot below can tell the cvs folder is in the views folder but I can´t see it in my sublime view.

I have restarted sublime and opened the app folder again but nothing happens, I can´t drag it to the view folder in sublime.

Have anyone experienced this?

[image]

Comment: Sublime has a "reload folders" button. See [how-to-force-folder-refresh-in-sublime-when-project-refresh-doesnt-work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051492/how-to-force-folder-refresh-in-sublime-when-project-refresh-doesnt-work)

Comment: it not working, I´m starting to think it might have something to do with naming of the folder, but that's just a quess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime's default settings file contains the following:

```
"folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", ".git", ".hg", "CVS"],
```

Since they default OS X file system is not case-sensitive, it will block any folder named `[Cc][Vv][Ss]` from being shown. To change this, open your user settings (**`Sublime Text → Preferences → Settings—User`**) and add the line from above, only removing `, "CVS"` part. Save the file, and you'll be all set.

Alternatively, if you don't want *any* folders to be blocked, use this in your user settings:

```
"folder_exclude_patterns": []
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems to be solved, if I rename the folder in finder from cvs to resume then it appears in sublime. But if I rename it again to cvs then it disappear from the view folder. So my conclusion is that this is happening because of the folder naming.

Comment: Does Sublime perhaps know about the old [CVS](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/cvs) revision control system?

Comment: Check the configuration settings for something about "ignore these files" or "invisible files". I don't know Sublime but the "cvs" name is awfully suspicious.